# Preview and Text Entry Switcher - Now you can have the preview on top!

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

Ever wanted to see the preview *above* the text entry box when composing a question or answer? If so, this is the script for you. It's a simple script that does exactly that. That's it.

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

Get it here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/preview_entry_switcher.user.js

#### Platform

Runs on any browser that supports UserScripts.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript and uses jQuery.